# Edited Child Theme's "header.php" but it doesn't appear to change the file

Tags: themes, child-theme, editor

So I logged into FTP and navigated to `/wp-content/themes/MyChildTheme/` and edited the `header.php` file. I saved the file and uploaded it and I can confirm the file has changed because if I check via cPanel or on a different computer I can see the new code.

However... if I go to WP-Admin and navigate to `Appearance > Editor > MyChildTheme > header.php` as you see below:

[image]

The file appears un-edited... I can't see the code that I added. I've cleared the LiteSpeed cache but it doesn't show the edited code still.

I've tried to edit the code from this page and it appears to have worked once but yet the actual change doesn't appear on the website... Whilst I said it appears to have worked once there still stills to be an issue with "Update file" because when I click the button it eventually times out but during this "timeout" the website is unreachable...

The button does the following for like 2 minutes:

[image]

It throws:

`Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.`

I'm not sure what's going wrong :/ any ideas

Comment: do you have cloudflare cache enabled?

Comment: Yes, but disabling it isn't doing anything either.

Comment: did you tried purge cache+put it in dev mode? anyways did you checked with file permissions?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. Tried all of them :(

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you uploaded in right path.
Then please upload file directly with cpanl.

I think your ftp doesn't right configuration

Comment: I know the path is correct, I'm not "uploading" per se, rather editing the file & saving (same as uploading)

I know it's all the correct path.

Comment: look a round, can you see any checkbox or notification?

Comment: What do you mean... I know without doubt that I am updating the correct file, I've been doing this for years it's only recently I've noticed its not changing anything.

Comment: you edit file in wordpress theme editor
when file not update 
a checkbox will apear 
are you see that?

Comment: No, no checkbox appears. See https://i.imgur.com/tKUwZjS.png